# Error de redireccion en NodeJs

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express

Tengo dos metodos en nodejs, uno GET para redireccionar la vista de un formulario, en donde capturo un dato y lo envio en POST para que me consulte en la base de datos, hasta el formulario todo va bien pero en el momento que lo envio me sale Cannot POST /users/diasRestantes/

```
router.get('/diasRestantes', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('users/diasRestantes');
});


router.post('/diasRestantes/:cedula', async(req, res)=>{
    const cedula = req.params;
    const users = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE cedula = ?', [cedula]);
    const fechaInicio = moment(users[0].fecha_registro);
    const fechaActual = moment();
    const dias = fechaInicio.diff(fechaActual, 'days');
    console.log(users);
    res.redirect('/users/dias', {users: users[0]}, {dias}); 

});
```

Y este es el form

```
<div class="container p-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
            <div class="card ">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2>Digitar cedula</h2>
                    <br>
                    <form action="/users/diasRestantes/{{cedula}}" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cedula" placeholder="Digite la cedula" >
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-dark">
                                Consultar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Que estoy haciendo mal? y que debo hacer para arreglarlo, les agradezco mucho.

Answer (score -1):

Si haces console.log(cedula) diría que te da undefined. O haces

const {cedula} = req.params
o haces
const cedula = req.params.cedula

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]